# ASCII characters Binder

Tags: c#, ascii, asciiencoding

In my application I have a textbox where you can enter ASCII characters that are displayed. 
If I type "عع" I typed the code in 1593 and 1593 is shown , but ASCII code  "ﻋ" and "ﻊ" are different!!

How do I show the difference?

Thanks

my code :

```
byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textBox1.Text);            

string s = "";
for (int j = 0; j < asciiBytes.Length; j++)
{
    s += ((int)asciiBytes[j]).ToString() + ", ";
}

MessageBox.Show(s);
```

Comment: What are the codes you are expecting?

Comment: @Asad please see my edit above

Comment: @Asad I expect to be different

Comment: But you're not using ASCII encoding anywhere, except for the name of your variable. I'm pretty sure ASCII doesn't even have code points for those characters.

Comment: I'm not sure. What are you trying to achieve? As I've mentioned in my answer below, both of those are the exact same character as far as Unicode, and indeed the Arabic language, are concerned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Arabic is a little rusty, but those both seem to be the letter [Ain](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0639/index.htm) (Unicode Character 'ARABIC LETTER AIN'), which is represented by code point 1359.

The reason they appear differently is because Unicode 1359, Ain, is a combining character, and the appearance is partly dictated by whether it is preceded or followed by other characters.